# pandas python передвинуть столбец

Tags: python, pandas

Есть такая таблица

| показатель | 2021(1) | 2021(2) | 2022(1) | 2022(2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 143 | 24 | 124 | 324 |
| b | 234 | 1 | 324 | 6583 |
| c | 2544 | 123 | 3424 | 61583 |
| d | 67 | 99 | 538 | 1000 |

Я хочу привести ее к следующему виду:

| показатель | полугодие | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 143 | 324 |
| a | 2 | 24 | 324 |
| b | 1 | 234 | 324 |
| b | 2 | 1 | 6583 |
| c | 1 | 2544 | 3424 |
| c | 2 | 123 | 61583 |
| d | 1 | 67 | 538 |
| d | 2 | 99 | 1000 |

то есть вытащить столбцы в пометкой (2)

Comment: Цифры между до и после не смотреть, они произвольные? Я так понимаю, просто нужно вертикально состыковать столбцы у которых до скобок название одинаковое?

Comment: поправила немного нужный вывод

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное можно короче, но я чисто "в лоб" всё сделал:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = """показатель    2021(1) 2021(2) 2022(1) 2022(2)
a   143 24  124 324
b   234 1   324 6583
c   2544    123 3424    61583
d   67  99  538 1000""".split('\n')
data = list(map(str.split, data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

df_list = []
for i in range(1, 3):
    columns = [col for col in df.columns if '(' not in col or f'({i})' in col]
    new_columns = [col.split('(')[0] for col in columns]
    df_tmp = df[columns].copy()
    df_tmp.columns = new_columns
    df_tmp['полугодие'] = i
    new_columns.insert(1, 'полугодие')
    df_list.append(df_tmp[new_columns])
df_new = pd.concat(df_list).sort_values(['показатель','полугодие'])
df_new
```

```
  показатель  полугодие  2021   2022
0          a          1   143    124
0          a          2    24    324
1          b          1   234    324
1          b          2     1   6583
2          c          1  2544   3424
2          c          2   123  61583
3          d          1    67    538
3          d          2    99   1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот еще вариант для разнообразия:

```
import re 
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"\(.\)$", "", regex=True)
res = pd.concat([pd.concat([df["показатель"],df.iloc[:,1::2]], axis=1),
                 pd.concat([df["показатель"],df.iloc[:,2::2]], axis=1)]).groupby("показатель").apply(lambda x:x)
res.index = [1 if not x&1 else 2 for x in res.index]
res.index.name = "полугодие"
res = res.reset_index()
```

res:

```
   полугодие показатель  2021   2022
0          1          a   143    124
1          1          a    24    324
2          2          b   234    324
3          2          b     1   6583
4          1          c  2544   3424
5          1          c   123  61583
6          2          d    67    538
7          2          d    99   1000
```

Answer (score 1):

альтернативный подход:

```
res = (df.melt(id_vars='показатель').
       assign(год=lambda x: x.variable.str[:4], полугодие=lambda x: x.variable.str[5]).
       pivot(index=['показатель','полугодие'],columns='год',values='value'))

print(res)
'''
год                   2021   2022
показатель полугодие             
a          1           143    124
           2            24    324
b          1           234    324
           2             1   6583
c          1          2544   3424
           2           123  61583
d          1            67    538
           2            99   1000
```

Comment: Не знаю почему, но этот способ у меня выводит только столбцы с годом, а с показателем и полугодием нет

Comment: @alina999, проверьте данные. вот с такими данными работает как показано в моем ответе: `data = {'показатель': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 '2021(1)': [143, 234, 2544, 67],
 '2021(2)': [24, 1, 123, 99],
 '2022(1)': [124, 324, 3424, 538],
 '2022(2)': [324, 6583, 61583, 1000]}` `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`